# Diagonalization of Block Matrices

Tags: diagonalization

Let $n>1$ and $A_1,A_2,A_3 \in M_n(F)$. Let $A$=\begin{bmatrix}A_{1}&A_{2}\\0_{n}&A_{3}\\\end{bmatrix} Prove the following. 
 
 1.) If $A_1$ and $A_3$ are diagonalizable, then $A$ is diagonalizable.(Does the converse of this is true?)

2.) If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A_1$ and of $A_3$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A_1 + A_3$.

Any and all help would be appreciated, please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Part (1) is wrong
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
0&1&1&0 \\
-1&0&0&1 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
0&0&-1&0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial are both $(x^2+1)^2$

Or, all real characteristic values:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
1&0&1&0 \\
0&3&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial are both $(x-1)^2 (x-3)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Both your statements are false!

1. Take $A_1=A_3=0_n$ and $A_2$ to be any non-zero matrix.
2. Take $A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ and $A_3=-A_2$. Then 1 is an eigenvalue of $A_1$ and $A_3$ but $A_1+A_3=0_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! What about the converse of $1$ does it have a counterexample?

Comment: The converse of 1 is fine. To understand diagonalisability, you have to look at the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)).